# Get JWT Token Created During User profile creation : Ember js

Tags: ember.js

I am using ember-simple-auth and jwt to authenticate a user profile, this is a code for signup and after signing up I wan't to print the token value created(which is in the response) in the console

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';

export default Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        signup: function(){
            var credentials = this.getProperties('name','identification','password');
            let list = this.store.createRecord('user', {
                name: credentials.name,
                email: credentials.identification,
                password: credentials.password
            });
            list.save();

        // I want to print the token value in console here

            this.setProperties({
                'name': '',
                'identification': '',
                'password': ''
            });


        }
    }
});
```

Comment: do you know where the token is stored?
is it in a service? is it in local storage? is it elsewhere? have you looked through the jwt addon code that you're using to see where it's stored?

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli its stored in the service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Sreenath, since you said the jwt is stored in a service,
This is how you'd console.log it.

---

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';

export default Controller.extend({
    nameOfService: service(),

    actions: {
        signup: function(){
            // ...

            // I want to print the token value in console here
            console.log(this.nameOfService.nameofPropertyThatJWTIsOn);

            // ...


        }
    }
});
```

Comment: if this is the answer to your question, please click the checkmark under the voting arrows, as it would award me points which encourages me to keep helping people on stack overflow :)

Comment: yeah sure @NullVoxPopuli